# Detecting when a celery task and all subtasks have completed

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a parent task that will spawn an arbitrary and potentially largish number of subtasks. Once both the parent and all of the subtasks have completed I need to set a flag in my database to indicate that it's ready. How would I best go about doing that?

For example:

```
@task()
def master_task(foo):
    foo_obj = Foo.objects.get(id=foo)
    for bar in foo_obj.bar_set.all():
        more_work.delay(bar.id)

@task()
def more_work(bar):
   bar_obj = Bar.objects.get(id=bar)
   do_work()
```

I need to detect when the master_task and all of the subtasks it has spawns have completed so that I can set a flag on a related model to indicate that everything is ready

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [chords](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords)

<del>You should use a [TaskSet][1]:
> The TaskSet enables easy invocation of several tasks at once, and is then able to join the results in the same order as the tasks were invoked.</del>

Comment: Note that "TaskSet has been removed, as it was replaced by the group construct in Celery 3.0."

Answer (score 2):

[celery.chord](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.chord) is designed precisely for that.